# Dynkin index of quotient map for a simple Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology

Let $G_1, G_2$ be simple compact Lie groups. Then $h_i := H_3(G_i, \mathbb Z)/ \mathrm{torsion} \cong \mathbb Z$. If $\phi : G_1 \to G_2$ is a homomorphism, then the pushforward $\phi_* : h_1 \to h_2$ carries a generator of $h_1$ to a generator of $h_2$ multiplied by some natural number $\mathrm{ind}(\phi)$, called the Dynkin index of $\phi$. I would like to ask if the value of the Dynkin index is known in the case that $\phi : G_1 \to G_2$ is a universal cover of $G_2$.

It is easy to see that for $G_2 = \mathrm{SO}(3)$ we have $\mathrm{ind}(\phi)=2$. I would like to know what happens for other groups.

Comment: I had not seen this definition of Dynkin index before: the one I am used to is that for simple compact Lie groups, $\pi_3(G_i)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and the Dynkin index is the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by multiplication by $\operatorname{ind}(\phi)$.  For this definition (which does *not* give the same answer as your definition), the answer for coverings is always $1$.

Comment: Dear @JasonDeVito I am not sure to what extent this is a standard definition. I certainly saw Dynkin index defined in terms of homology groups somewhere, but it might be that those authors considered simply-connected Lie groups only, in which case the two definitions do agree. In any case, the question I'm asking now has come up quite naturally in my attempts to understand certain aspects of the theory of characteristic classes.

Comment: I haven't worked out the details, but here's a thought:  If $B$ is the negative of the Killing form on $G$, then $B$ gives a bi-invariant metric on $G$.  Then one can form the $3$-form $\omega(X,Y,Z) = B(X,[Y,Z])$.  It turns out that $\omega$ generates $H^3(G;\mathbb{R})$.  It *may* be natural enough that the element it represents in $H^3(G;\mathbb{R})$ can be identified as the image of $1\in H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})$ in under the map $H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{R}\cong H^3(G;\mathbb{R})$.  I'm being little sloppy here because $H^3(G;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus T$ for some ....

Comment: torsion group $T$, and while $T$ is uniquely defined as a subgroup of $H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})$, the $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't.  Nonetheless, the image of $(1, t)$ in $H^3(G;\mathbb{R})$ is the same regardless of the value of $t\in T$, so I think it's ok.  Anyway, if this form works like that, then you can compute the map $H^3(G_2,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^3(G_1,\mathbb{Z})$ by pulling back the form $\omega$ and integrating.  Since $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same Lie algebra, I think it follows that the Dynkin index is simply the degree of the covering.  But admittedly, this is a lot of guess work.

Comment: Ha, some googling brought up *your* previous question about properly normalizing this three form.  So it seems like a trick like this should work, once someone figures out the normalization.

Comment: I think normalization I proposed in the question you are referring to  (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603441/normalization-of-the-generator-of-third-cohomology-of-a-compact-lie-group?noredirect=1#comment7409287_3603441) is correct for simply-connected Lie groups, in the sense that it provides a generator of the real image of $H^3(G, \mathbb Z)$.This is proven is Pressley, Segal and I think they simply missed a factor, otherwise the reasoning seems sound. I am trying to figure out what is the correct normalization for groups which are not simply-connected, hence the question.

Comment: For the reference, the proof in the simply-connected case goes as follows: first compute the normalization in the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ case, then use the fact that images of pushforwards in homology through homomorphisms $\mathrm{SU}(2) \to G$ induced by coroots generate $H_3(G, \mathbb Z)$. The last statement is false e.g. for $G= \mathrm{SO}(3)$.